# Is it a good practice to use a proxy.conf.json in angular?

Tags: angular

Say we have a server running on http://localhost:8080/.

Instead of setting up back-end's base URL from environment.ts file, we can write a proxy.conf.json file with the following code,

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And to run the app,

```
ng serve  —-proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Here, we re-route all calls to the target URL defined in the proxy.conf.json file, so that we can bypass the proxy.

Is this a safe way? What does **"security": false** means?

Comment: do not worry about security because any way this applies only in development mode, yes we can use `proxy.conf.json`. in production if you are deploying backend and angular in same server

Comment: When angular app is required to be deployed in a tomcat server, people usually follow this approach. So can there be any security concern if the app is deployed in any kubernetes environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secure option comes from the `http-proxy` [libary](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#https---http).

> Using HTTPS
>
> You can activate the validation of a secure SSL
> certificate to the target connection (avoid self-signed certs), just
> set secure: true in the options.